# python Tkinter get() value from Entry Field

Tags: python, tkinter

I have getting confused in getting the value from the Tkinter() Entry Field. I have this kind of code...

```
from Tkinter import*

def valueGET(val1, val2):
    print val1 + "  " + val2

class ContentUI():
def showLogin(self, frame):

        self.contentUI = ContentUI()    

        L1 = Label(frame, text="Name")
        L1.pack( side = LEFT)
        L1.grid()

        E1 = Entry(frame, bd =5)
        E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
        E1.grid()

        L2 = Label(frame, text="Secret")
        L2.pack( side = LEFT)
        L2.grid()       

        E2 = Entry(frame, bd =5, show="*")
        E2.pack(side = RIGHT)
        E2.grid()

        submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", width=15, command=valueGET(E1.get(), E2.get())) 
        submit.grid()

class UIDisplay():
    def play(self):
        root = Tk()

        root.title(title)
        root.geometry(dimension)

        app = Frame(root)

        contentUI = ContentUI()
        contentUI.showLogin(app)

        app.grid()


        root.mainloop()

adkooPlay = UIDisplay()
adkooPlay.play()
```

but it seems my valueGET(val1, val2) method is not working, it didn't print the value or even get it by using the get() method of the Tkinter() Entry, did I do wrong? and how should it be done?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code call `valueGET` even before `submit` button is created.  Then it pass the return value of the function to Button constructor as `command` argument.

To register the function as callback, replace folloiwng line:

```
submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", width=15, command=valueGET(E1.get(), E2.get()))
```

with:

```
submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", width=15, command=lambda: valueGET(E1.get(), E2.get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need brackets in the print command in your function

```
def valueGET(val1, val2):
    print val1 + "  " + val2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This 4-year-old question already has an accepted and up-voted answer. Your efforts would be more appreciated by people who have recent questions that are still waiting to be answered.

Comment: It seems that you only know python 3. In python 2, print does **not** need brackets. So your answer is basically pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root =tk.Tk()
mystring =tk.StringVar(root)
def getvalue():
    print(mystring.get())
e1 = Entry(root,textvariable = mystring,width=100,fg="blue",bd=3,selectbackground='violet').pack()
button1 = tk.Button(root, 
                text='Submit', 
                fg='White', 
                bg= 'dark green',height = 1, width = 10,command=getvalue).pack()

root.mainloop()
```