# Taking in a user input to load a program

Tags: python, tkinter

Within a revision application I'm developing, I'm looking to take in a user answer (of which area of revision they would like to focus upon) which will then load the specific area they need.

Would this require entry widgets?

This is the code I have so far:

```
instruction = tkinter.Label(roots, text= "'What would you like to revise?'\n")    
instruction.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)
if int(answer) != int(entryWidget.get().strip()):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Answer", "INCORRECT!")
else:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Answer", "CORRECT!")
```

I apologize for the lack of code, but I'm unsure on how to develop it past this point without knowing how to load my alternate part of code from this point

part 2:

```
def Signup():
    global pwordE
    global nameE
    global roots

    roots = tkinter.Tk()
    roots.title("Computer Science Revision")
    roots.geometry("1000x1000")
    roots.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
    roots.configure(background="#a1dbcd")    

    photo= tkinter.PhotoImage(roots,file="ryu.gif")
    A = tkinter.Label(roots,image=photo)
    A.pack()    

    roots = tkinter.Tk()
    roots.title('Signup')
    instruction = tkinter.Label(roots, text= 'Please enter new Credentials\n')
    instruction.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)

    nameL =  tkinter.Label(roots, text='New Username: ')
    pwordL =  tkinter.Label(roots, text='New Password: ')
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    nameE= tkinter.Entry(roots)
    pwordE = tkinter.Entry(roots, show='*')
    nameE.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1)

    signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup)
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop()

    roots.title("Computer Science Revision")
    roots.geometry("1000x1000")
    roots.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
    roots.configure(background="#a1dbcd")    

    photo= tkinter.PhotoImage(roots,file="ryu.gif")
    A = tkinter.Label(roots,image=photo)
    A.pack()
```

This part will not load with the rest of the login, how can I fix this?

Comment: One approach might be using an entry widget and an elif statement to select which area of study the user is interested in. Alternatively, have some buttons with pre-defined areas such as history, science, maths and have each button open/generate the relevant interface.

Comment: As in the user simply presses the button for the specific area of revision?

Comment: Yes, because presumably you have coded a few different areas, so displaying all the options with easy-to-access buttons seems like a good idea to me

Comment: Never really thought of that approach, i'll give it a try. How would I go about coding all the buttons on one platform after they've gone through my login process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope you are asking something like this one.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+100+100")
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)
f3 = tk.Frame(root)
f4 = tk.Frame(root)

for frame in (f1,f2,f3,f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

#Frame1

button1 = tk.Button(f1, text='English', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).pack()
button2 = tk.Button(f1, text='Maths', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3)).pack()
button3 = tk.Button(f1, text='Science', command=lambda:raise_frame(f4)).pack()


#Frame2

tk.Label(f2, text="English Revision").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

#Frame3
tk.Label(f3, text="Maths Revision").pack()
tk.Button(f3, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

#Frame4
tk.Label(f4, text="Science Revision").pack()
tk.Button(f4, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this - where would I place the code to go within my buttons? under each individual frame?

Comment: Yes, By creating multiple frames, we can use `tkraise()` to raise particular frame on clicking the button. so You need to add stuffs to the frame which linked to the button. Similarly you can use login stuff too. But my code is just a sample one without Object oriented approach.

Comment: Great stuff thanks, one more question if you know how to help... I've edited my question

Comment: I mean you are trying to add signup related process, you need to integrate any database to do it, verify the link for simple db sqlite https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/ and try to integrate it.

Comment: great thanks I've done that... how can I add information within my buttons? ive tried to make it as a label but im getting this error? AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: You can't add Information to the buttons you can only call a function when the button is clicked. That function should have the conditions of login. You need to use `get()` method to get the value entered in the entry and match it with the conditional statements (if else) to set the `raise_frame()` method. If the value matches as per the condition make the raise the frame.
 check out the following links to how the `get()` method works.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403386/python-tkinter-get-value-from-entry-field

Comment: still not too sure on what you mean...could you show an example?