# Retrieve the input value of an entry - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just getting started with making basic GUI's with Tkinter.
I have previously created a script in python and I wanted to create a basic GUI for it.

My issue is I need to get the value of an entry widget to use as a parameter value, but methods online are not working for me.

This is what I am trying.

```
def retrieve_input():
    eq_input = eq_textbox.get()
    return eq_input


equation_input = retrieve_input()
```

eq_textbox is my entry and equation_input will be the parameter value.

Comment: What is the problem actually?

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry) Does this answer your question? [python-tkinter-get-value-from-entry-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403386)

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

entry_var = StringVar()                                      #initializing a string var
eq_textbox     = Entry(window, textvariable = entry_var)     #add textvariabe to store value

def retrieve_input():
    eq_input = entry_var.get()                     #see here
    return eq_input

equation_input = retrieve_input()
```

window.mainloop()

**You need a varible to store that value... see above**

Comment: You can get the content of a `Entry` widget by `get()` without using tkinter variable.  Using tkinter variable can simplify the update of the content by calling`set()` and no need to call `delete()` and `insert()` on the `Entry` widget.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please clarify what StringVar() does? Could I not just write entry_var = ""  I believed that empty speech marks initialized a string variable.

Comment: Yeah that's nearly the same thing. I have habbit of initializing in this way.