# How do I get return a value from a function that is a tkinter entry.get()

Tags: tkinter

So what I am trying to do is create a function that packs tkinter Entry widget and create a button that says 'confirm' and command it executes is lambda: return entry.get(). But this doesn't seem to work.
Its a long piece of code so here is some part of it:-

```
def remove():
    take=tk.Label(frame3,text="Enter No.of Coins to take this Round")
    take.place(rely=0.18,relx=0.1)
    takeent=tk.Entry(frame3)
    takeent.place(rely=0.18,relx=0.35)
    cofirmbut=tk.Button(frame3,text="Confirm",command=lambda:takeent.get())
    cofirmbut.place(rely=0.25,relx=0.2)
```

And I also want to limit entry to the widget to{1, 3, 4}

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
So the function should return a value from the entry after the button has been clicked .Thanks @acw1668 for options Menu.

Comment: Use `OptionMenu` or `Combobox` instead if you want to limit choices.  Returning value from a callback assigned to `command` option of `Button` is meaningless because it is discarded.  Just get the value of the `Entry` whenever you want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-tkinter-get-value-from-entry-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best options is to work with text variables like so:

```py
var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
```

Then you can use both:
`var.set(string)` & `var.get() #-> return current input`