# Tkinter: get value from entry with button and store in variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Say that we have an `entry_object`, a button `button_object` and a global variable called `score`.

I want to update the `score` when the button is clicked and the entry has a value. I tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403386/python-tkinter-get-value-from-entry-field) answer but I need something slightly different. The main difference is the storing of the value in a variable.

I have a function to generate the elements:

```
def generate_gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('900x700+50+50')
    entry_object = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
    entry_object.pack()
    button_object = tk.Button(root, text='submit')
    button_object.pack()
    return root, entry_object, button_object
```

I now want to update `score` with `entry_object.get()' when the button is clicked.

```
generate_gui()
while accumulated_score < 10:
    for player in players:
        ** #### pseudocode: if button_object clicked then player.accumulated_score += score#### **
```

How do I replace the pseudocode with the right code? Please help :)

Comment: Research for tk.StringVar or IntVar and use the option of text variable. In addition, for GUI code you usually don't use a while loop, since the event loop is driven.

Comment: You mention several player objects but don't have any player objects in the code you posted. Also, you don't have any sort of widget for displaying a score.

Answer (score 0):

#If score is a global variable then:

```
score = 0
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x700+50+50')
entry_object = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_object.pack()

def increment():
    global score
    score += 1

button_object = tk.Button(root, text='submit', command=increment() )
root.mainloop()
```

#If it's an atribute from an object "player" then:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x700+50+50')
entry_object = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_object.pack()

def increment():
   for player in players:
       if player.accumulated_score <= 10:
            player.accumulated_score += score
button_object = tk.Button(root, text='submit', command=increment() )
root.mainloop()
```